# cpp: define class member variable type by type passed to constructor

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to define a type of a member variable using the type of a parameter passed to the constructor in C++. Is this possible?

I tried in C++14 but I got an compilation error: `error: missing template arguments before ‘a’`

I think of something like this:

```
template <typename SOMETYPE>
class A {
    public:
  SOMETYPE membervariable;
  A(int foo, SOMETYPE bar){};
 
};
 
int main() 
{
    A<char> a = A(123, 'z');
}
```

but instead of using `A<char> a = A(123, 'z')` I would like to create it like so `A a = A(123, 'z')` - so in essence I would like to drop the template parameter and let the compiler deduce the type from the second argument.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to have to use template notation when declaring the variable (`A<char>`)?

Comment: I don't understand the problem? Seems to compile just [fine](https://godbolt.org/z/r5fbos). In c++17 at least.

Comment: Are you looking for [deduction guides](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)?

Comment: @cigien you should mention that this only works for c++17

Comment: @scohe001 Yes, because I would like to pass a lambda expression to the constructor and store it in the class to call it later but I would like to avoid the overhead of std::callable

Comment: @RoQuOTriX True, edited the comment. I just assume the latest available standard, unless otherwise mentioned :)

Comment: Sorry about that, so the answer is "Yes, just use c++17" :D I only tried 14 and never thought about that this is something that might be added in 17. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, before c++17, there is no deduction for class templates.

Comment: So if you would create an answer I would accept it as the one which solved the issue :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++14 and before, you would have a corresponding `make_T` factory function:

```cpp
template<class SOMETYPE>
A<SOMETYPE> make_A(int foo, SOMETYPE bar)
{
    return A<SOMETYPE>(foo, std::move(bar));
}

// Sometimes spelt `A::make` or `A::create`,
// but the standard library uses `make_pair`, `make_tuple`, etc.

int main() 
{
    auto a = make_A(123, 'z');
}
```

In C++17, [class template argument deduction (CTAD)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction) was introduced. This lets you use a template class's name without specifying template arguments, and they would be deduced like function template arguments.

So in C++17/20, you could just do any of:

```cpp
A a{123, 'z'};
A a = A(123, 'z');
auto a = A(123, 'z');
```